# Jenkins custom context path name

Tags: java, spring, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to build a Spring Boot application. I used the deploy to container plugin as a post build step to deploy to Tomcat. There I could give the context path and the war file will be created by the name I give there.
But now I want to pick a name from a file that is stored centrally, meaning I want Jenkins to read a file and get the name that matches criteria.

Is there a way to write some script for this purpose.